# Reset counter of semaphore in WinAPI

Tags: c, winapi, visual-c++, semaphore

I have a queue with one consumer and multiple producers. It is based on Semaphore created with `CreateSemaphore()`.

While queue is empty Semaphore is set to zero. Producer puts message to a queue and increments counter so consumer waits for item in a queue.

There is a case that requires to clear queue. That means that semaphore counter must be reset to `0`.

Unfortunately, I did not found an option on MSDN to reset counter. Usage of `WaitForSingleObject()` while counter is not zeroed creates racing conditions, so doesn't seem to be an option.

Is there any another way to reset semaphore counter in Windows?

Comment: Sure, that's a race if you only use a semaphore.  It just can't get the job done so don't use it, use the [built-in support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681930%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: To purge a queue such as this, you first have to ensure that no more items get pushed to it.  After that, you can pop all existing items and destroy them.  There is no option on MSDN to reset counter because it it not a supported operation for a semaphore, nor should it be.

Comment: @rcgldr 'Set thread priority higher to prevent producer threads from running' will not work reliably on a machine with more than one core since the producer threa\ds may run anyway.  It won't work reiably on a box with one core either since a page-fault ma allow a producer thread to run.

Comment: You already have a race condition where you want to clear the queue and reset the semaphore. What happens if somebody looks at the semaphore after you clear the queue? Whatever solution you use there can be expanded to protect the drainage of the semaphore.

Comment: @MartinJames  - The discussion was getting too long, so I deleted my prior posts. I'll delete this one later.

Comment: @RaymondChen Nothing should happen if I reset semaphore first and clear queue after that.

Comment: Suppose the queue has 1 item. A thread waiting on the semaphore is woken. That thread then gets pre-empted, and you atomically reset the semaphore and clear the queue. That thread then resumes execution and goes to look at the queue, but the queue is empty. Oops.

Comment: @Alex: if it's safe to atomically reset the semaphore and then clear the queue then it should be safe to non-atomically drain the semaphore and then clear the queue.

Comment: @RaymondChen Agreed in general, but in a current case message queue is cleared by a consumer, so there is no problem here.

Comment: If the consumer wants to clear the queue, then it can just wait on the semaphore, pull a work item, throw it away, then wait on the semaphore some more, and repeat until the semaphore remains unsignaled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literal answer: no, you cannot atomically reset a semaphore.

---

In the single consumer case, you probably shouldn't be using a semaphore in the first place.  An auto-reset event is sufficient, with a consumer loop like this:

- try to pop an item from the queue
- if successful, process it; return to top of loop
- if the queue is empty, wait on the event, then return to top of loop

With this logic, you can clear the queue without needing to do anything to the event.

Note that if the producer/consumer logic can be integrated with the queue's own locking mechanism, it may be more efficient to use a condition variable.

---

A more generic option for the single consumer case (assuming a FIFO queue) is to set a flag for the consumer, then add a guard message at the end of the queue.

Whenever the consumer takes a message off the queue, it can check the flag, and if set, discard all messages until the guard message arrives.

(If another queue clear might be attempted while the consumer is still processing a previous one, then you need some additional locking.  This can just be an auto-reset event that is set initially, waited on before setting the flag, and then set again by the consumer when it sees the guard message.)

---

In the multiple consumer case, one simple approach is to use a SRW lock (as Hans suggested) in combination with a semaphore:

- To add an item to the queue, obtain a reader ("shared") lock, add the item, increment the semaphore, release the lock.
- To remove an item from the queue, wait for the semaphore, obtain a reader ("shared") lock, remove the item, release the lock.
- To empty the queue, obtain a writer ("exclusive") lock, clear out the queue, repeatedly wait for the semaphore until it is empty, release the lock.

In rare instances, at the point where you obtained the writer lock, one of the consumer threads will have just decremented the semaphore and be about to try obtaining a reader lock.  When that thread finally gets the lock, it will find that the queue is empty.  This is harmless, though if you wanted to, you could detect threads in this state (by noticing that the number of items removed from the queue was greater than the number of times you decremented the semaphore) and leave one or more dummy items in the queue for them to find and discard.

Comment: Once the producer acquired an exclusive lock on the SRW then it can party on the queue freely.  No additional semaphore required.

Comment: @HansPassant: the semaphore is so that the consumer can wait efficiently when the queue is empty.  I couldn't figure out any way to do that with just an SRW.  (Also, I'm assuming that the queue itself is already thread-safe; in this model, neither the semaphore nor the SRW protect it.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston - There's only one consumer thread, but multiple producers. The sequencing within the producers isn't explained. I'm assuming there's a free pool of messages that the producers draw messages from and that the consumer returns back to. There's a potential issue if any producer has already retrieved a message from the free pool but is currently waiting for some other event, unrelated to the shared lock.

Comment: @rcgldr: good catch! I hadn't noticed that; I was assuming multiple consumers. That means that there was no point in using a semaphore in the first place.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - the issue is a producer holding onto an unfilled message from the free pool while waiting for some other event, while at the  same time, the consumer thread wants to clear (empty) the message queue.

Comment: @rcgldr: in a typical implementation, emptying the message queue won't affect or be affected by messages that haven't yet been added to the queue.  But yes, if the queue has unusual semantics they would need to be taken into account.  Ideally the consumer/producer logic would be integrated into the queue logic anyway.

Comment: The original poster hasn't provided enough information to know what the goal is when clearing the consumer's input queue while the producers are still active.

Answer (score 0):

How about calling WaitForSingleObject(semaphore, 0) to attempt to obtain the semaphore with 0 waiting time? This effectively resets a single count semaphore. You may need to repeat the call if has multiple counts.

```
while (WaitForSingleObject(handle, 0) == WAIT_OBJECT_0);
```